# prove that $C$ assumes all the values $x, 0\leq x\leq mn-1$, $x$ is prime to $mn$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\gcd (m,n)=1$.

$$A=\{x\mid 0\leq x \leq n-1 \text{ and } x \text{ is prime to } m\}$$

$$B= \{x\mid 0\leq x \leq n-1 \text{ and } x \text{ is prime to } n\}.$$

If $C =\{na+mb\mid a\in A\text{ and } b \in B\}$ then prove that $C$ assumes all the values $x, 0\leq x\leq mn-1$, $x$ is prime to $mn$.

In the problem, above I am not able to understand how to represent $C$. Provide me a hint and the concept behind it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the set B it is x<n

Comment: In the Set A and Set B x < n. In A (x,m)=1 and in B (x,n)=1

Comment: There is a mistake. Take m=17, n=19, a=15, b=16. na+mb > mn-1

Comment: Then I think there is a problem in the question. Anyway, if we replace n to m in B. How will that be ?

Comment: No change. I have taken both m and n greater than a and b

Comment: I think the question wants the solver to find the fault. But in the problem set there is no such information regarding that.

Comment: The sets $A$ and $B$ are both the same set.  Why define them separately rather than just one of them? $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy No. We can take $a $ which is a factor of n but not m.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN : Oh.  Sorry -- I should have been more alert. $\qquad$